# How to conduct E-commerce transactions, XMR to GBP and conversion to fiat without KYC registration documents

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-rpc, payment-integration

I'd be grateful for some advice and help. I’m not a web developer and have basic knowledge of html and even less of crypto language.

What I want to do is sell items on a website where customers pay in Monero. But I want the amount to show in GBP for example customers, click an item and the price shows £10. I then want the XMR sent to my wallet, and eventually exchanged for GBP.

I want the whole setup to be as private as possible, with no KYC or other documents needed to register.

There is Vigla but it doesn’t convert to fiat it only accepts Monero.  There is Globee but it requires KYC and extensive registration documents.

so in essence I need to know:

**1. Is there a fiat to XMR convertor an ecommerce site owner can use? The customer should be able to click a button to buyan item priced £10, and be presented with the converted amount in XMR to pay from their XMR wallet.**

**2. Is there an exchange that can do an XMR to GBP fiat conversion that
    doesn’t require KYC registration?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The converter should be easy enough via JSON through most exchanges' APIs.  I've done it in bash with curl and jq.  The no KYC to pull funds out to fiat, well that is more of a sticky wicket.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=gbp&ids=monero'  | jq . | grep current_price | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d',' -f1
```

in bash will return the current GBP of Monero.  You can do your math on price from there.